# Apache Camel: Download Multiple Files at once using SFTP component

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

on sftp i have several files with following xyz names:

```
40_20200313_0cd6963f-bf5b-4eb0-b310-255a23ed778e_p.dat
123_20200313_0cd6963f-bf5b-4eb0-b310-255a23ed778e_p.dat
etc.
```

I want camel to download all files at once as currently it is downloading file one by one.

Following is camel route and query:

```
    private static String regex() {
        return "(22|23|24|25|26|28|29|32|35|40|41|46|52|70|85|88|123)_(?:.*)_p.dat";
    }

    private static String sftpComponent() {
        return "sftp://transit.ergogroup.no/Eyeshare/From_Eyeshare_Test"
                + "?username=Eyeshare_test"
                + "&password=epw3ePOugG" // Stored on wildfly server
                + "&download=true" //Shall be read chunk by chunk to avoid heap space issues. Earlier download=true was used: Harpreet
                + "&useList=true"
                + "&stepwise=false"
                + "&disconnect=true"
                + "&passiveMode=true"
                + "&reconnectDelay=10000"
//              + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true"
                + "&delay=300000"
                //+ "&fileName=" + sftpFileName
//              + "&include=kiki\\.txt"
//              + "&include=40_*_p\\.dat"sss
                + "&include="+regex()
                + "&preMove=$simple{file:onlyname}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.processing"
                + "&move=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.success"
                + "&moveFailed=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.failed";
//              + "&idempotentRepository=#infinispan"
//              + "&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true";
    }

   from(sftpComponent()).log("CHU").to(archiveReceivedFile())
```

Code appears fine but output is not. Anyone kindly suggest

Comment: Why you asking many questions and ignore answers on them ? What if another will have same problems and find your questions ?

Comment: @c0ld: It is not like that. You can check my whole history from beginning. I am accepting answers, trying things, some on hold, and also giving my answers. How can i accept answers unnecessarily and confuse others? Request you to go through whole thanks

Comment: I open ur profile and last 10 questions are white =) Yeah some of them are without answers but with helping comments. Ok it's ur decision. Let's back to question. Considering name archiveReceivedFile() you want create archive from consumed batch of files ? Just need to know more about case because consuming unknown number of files at same time is not good idea.

Comment: @c0ld: Your understanding is correct. Ok, so i should consume it one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Here some example of [aggregator](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html):

```
from("file:///somePath/consume/?maxMessagesPerPoll=2&delay=5000")
            .aggregate(constant(true), new ZipAggregationStrategy()).completion(exchange -> exchange.getProperty("CamelBatchComplete", Boolean.class))
            .to("file:///somePath/produce/")
```

Here maxMessagesPerPoll defining how many files will be archived. But if number of them in folder is lower then maxMessagesPerPoll value it will wait for missing files for complete archive.  Here example of ZipAggregationStrategy:

```
private static class ZipAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    private ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream out;
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(final Exchange oldExchange, final Exchange newExchange) {
        try {
            if (oldExchange == null) {
                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);
            }
            createEntry(newExchange);
            return newExchange;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    private void createEntry(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class));
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try (InputStream body = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class)) {
            while ((length = body.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(final Exchange exchange) {
        try {
            zipOutputStream.close();
            exchange.getIn().setBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, "someArchive.zip");
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's in-memory example. You can improve it for example with using temporary file. And you can always create your own completion predicate based on your logic.

UPD: i think link for documentation is temporary unavailable

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand how this answer is related to the question. It seems to me that the question is "how to concurrently download files from an SFTP" but this answer is about how to archive a batch of files or something like that.